# Linq to determine if a value occurs more than x number of times

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects which have a JobCode which is a string value. We have a business rule that says within the collection we should never have more than 4 elements who's JobCode is the same. I am struggling with this because usually I am comparing against some known value external to the list rather than comparing the list to itself.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can identify your bad jobs with:

```
Jobs.GroupBy(j => j.JobCode).Where(g => g.Count() > 4)
```

It's not clear what remedial action you wish to take...

Comment: Ah, it was the groupby part I was missing which seems to make a subcollection to apply critera to. Thanks (4mins left to accept)

Answer (score 8):

You could group by your string property, then check if there is any group with more than 4 elements:

```
bool test = jobs.GroupBy(z => z.MyString).Any(z => z.Count() > 4);
```

Answer (score 7):

You would use `GroupBy` on the collection and than `Count` on the resulting groups:

```
var jobCodesWithMoreThanFourOccurences = collection.GroupBy(x => x.JobCode)
                                                   .Where(x => x.Count() > 4)
                                                   .Select(x => x.Key);
```

The `Key` we select at the end is the property we used as a key in the `GroupBy`, i.e. it will contain the `JobCode`.