# Display match for only 3 consecutive numbers

Tags: c#

How can I display only 3 consecutive numbers for example in my code below I only want it to return 4, as that appears 3 times.

9 is 4 times so do not want that and 7 is twice so not what want that.

The code I currently have display 9

```
int[] intArray = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7 };

var adjacentDuplicateNumbers = intArray
    .Skip(1)
    .Where((value, index) => value == intArray[index])
    .Distinct();

var enumerable = adjacentDuplicateNumbers as int[] ?? adjacentDuplicateNumbers.ToArray();
if (enumerable.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a consecutive number and is repeated 3 times.", enumerable.First());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no consecutive number found.");
}
```

Comment: Basicly http://stackoverflow.com/q/14457319/447156 ?

Comment: What if the number appears twice as consecutive triple?

Answer (score 3):

Using the extension method of this post: [LINQ to find series of consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469416/linq-to-find-series-of-consecutive-numbers)

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, T, bool> condition)
{
  T prev = seq.First();
  List<T> list = new List<T>() { prev };

  foreach (T item in seq.Skip(1))
  {
    if (condition(prev, item) == false)
    {
      yield return list;
      list = new List<T>();
    }
    list.Add(item);
    prev = item;
  }

  yield return list;
}
```

Usage:

```
var res = intArray.GroupWhile((a, b) => a == b).
          Where(x => x.Count() == 3).Select(x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple foor loop is enough (and should be faster than linq)

```
int[] intArray = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7 };
var minus2 = intArray[0];
var minus1 = intArray[1];
var result = new List<int>();
for(int i = 2; i < intArray.Length; i++)
{
    var current = intArray[i];
    if(minus2 == minus1 && minus1 == current)
    {
        result.Add(current);
    }
    minus2 = minus1;
    minus1 = current;
}
```

Comment: your `for` is missing a `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = intArray.Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => intArray.Count(x => x == v))
    .Where(x => x.Value == 3)
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Take the district elements in the array. Use these as keys in a dictionary that map to the number of occurrences of this key in the original array. Use `Where` to only select pairs that match the required count (3). Use `Select` to return the resulting keys - in this example only 4.